# Unable to use Remmina in Ubuntu Mate Environment

Tags: remote-desktop

I can use Desktop Sharing and Remminna in Ubuntu Environment but cannot use it or find any option like sharing in Ubuntu Mate Environment.

Comment: I have the same issue and I checked also if it works with the newest Remmina, but it doesn't work as well. Did you make it work in the meantime?